# how can i get conditonal hourly mean in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, mean

i have below dataframe. and i wanna make a hourly mean dataframe 
condition that every hour just calculate mean value 00:15:00~00:45:00.
date/time are multi index.

```
                       aaa
date       time             
2017-01-01 00:00:00   146.88
           00:15:00   143.28
           00:30:00   143.28
           00:45:00   141.12
           01:00:00   134.64
           01:15:00   132.48
           01:30:00   136.80
           01:45:00   138.24
           02:00:00   131.76
           02:15:00   131.04
           02:30:00   134.64
           02:45:00   139.68
           03:00:00   136.08
           03:15:00   132.48
           03:30:00   132.48
           03:45:00   139.68
           04:00:00   134.64
           04:15:00   131.04
           04:30:00   160.56
           04:45:00   177.12
            ...
```

results should be belows.. how can i do it?

```
                      aaa
date       time             
2017-01-01 00:00:00   146.88
           01:00:00   134.64
           02:00:00   131.76
           03:00:00   136.08
           04:00:00   134.64
            ...
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: actually i don't have much idea..just think steps 1. groupby(level=0), 2. apply 00:15:00~45:00, 3. mean .. but not good at using pandas code it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems need only select rows with `00:00` in the end of times:

```
df2 = df1[df1.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str).str.endswith('00:00')]
print (df2)
                        aaa
date       time            
2017-01-01 00:00:00  146.88
           01:00:00  134.64
           02:00:00  131.76
           03:00:00  136.08
           04:00:00  134.64
```

But if need mean only values `00:15-00:45` it is more complicated:

```
lvl1 = pd.Series(df1.index.get_level_values(1))
m = ~lvl1.astype(str).str.endswith('00:00')
lvl1new = lvl1.mask(m).ffill()

df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1.index.get_level_values(0),
                                       lvl1new.where(m)], names=df1.index.names)
print (df1)
                        aaa
date       time            
2017-01-01 NaN       146.88
           00:00:00  143.28
           00:00:00  143.28
           00:00:00  141.12
           NaN       134.64
           01:00:00  132.48
           01:00:00  136.80
           01:00:00  138.24
           NaN       131.76
           02:00:00  131.04
           02:00:00  134.64
           02:00:00  139.68
           NaN       136.08
           03:00:00  132.48
           03:00:00  132.48
           03:00:00  139.68
           NaN       134.64
           04:00:00  131.04
           04:00:00  160.56
           04:00:00  177.12
```

---

```
df = df1['aaa'].groupby(level=[0,1]).mean()
print (df)
date        time    
2017-01-01  00:00:00    142.56
            01:00:00    135.84
            02:00:00    135.12
            03:00:00    134.88
            04:00:00    156.24
Name: aaa, dtype: float64
```

Comment: You are welcome! I was a bit confused, because expected output was different ;)